# How to make Http request load on time before table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, openweathermap

I may be missing a design or simple detail here as I'm new to iOS, but can't figure this one out:

I've got a `func` called `getWeatherData()`, that based on the location received from another view controller, gets weather conditions from a `http` request and assigns it to HikeModel. This function is called in method of `ViewDidLoad()`.

After `func` gets the weather conditions, it passes this to a child view controller. Which Child VC is a Table View Controller. 
Problem is my `TableViewCell` loads faster than the http request takes to be done, in the parent view controller. And when the cell labels and images try to retrieve information that should have values assigned, theirs is nothing, since the `http` request hasn't finished on time.

I also attempted using `DispatchQueue.main.async` but no difference was shown.

I'm doing a native `http` request with Swift4.

For more detail on the structure of my project, I'm doing based on this work: https://medium.com/@phillfarrugia/re-creating-the-siri-shortcuts-drawer-interaction-9b2bc94e0b05

In `ViewDidLoad`

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()

DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    self.getWeatherData(hikeLocation: self.startHikeLocationString)
    group.leave()
}
```

Method sending information `fillDrawer`, with what should contain weather vars assigned to HikeModel.

```
private func configureDrawerViewController() {
    let compressedHeight = ExpansionState.height(forState: .compressed, inContainer: view.bounds)
    let compressedTopConstraint = view.bounds.height - compressedHeight
    containerViewTopConstraint.constant = compressedTopConstraint
    previousContainerViewTopConstraint = containerViewTopConstraint.constant

    // NB: Handle this in a more clean and production ready fashion.
    if let drawerViewController = children.first as? DrawerViewController {
        //send distnace too
        drawerViewController.delegate = self
        drawerViewController.fillDrawer(hike: self.hikeModel, userLocation: self.userLocation) 
    }
```

TableView CellsForRowAt

```
cell.temperature.text = hikeModel.temperature
cell.weather.text = hikeModel.weather
cell.weatherIcon.text = hikeModel.weatherIcon
cell.humidity.text = hikeModel.humidity
cell.barometer.text = hikeModel.barometer
cell.sunrise.text = hikeModel.sunrise
cell.sunset.text = hikeModel.sunset
```

I expect the `tableViewCell` in child controller to load after the `http` request is done in parent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete to identify issue but you should have to do like:

1) load data from webservice then,

2) reload tableView

In your `ViewDidLoad`

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.getWeatherData(hikeLocation: self.startHikeLocationString)
           group.leave()
        }
```

add line after complete process of data modeling and it should be in **mainQueue**

```
yourtable.reloadData()
```